# How to override a public var in framework?

Tags: swift, frameworks

in my own cocoa touch framework

```
open class BLE: NSObject,CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate {

  public var myCentralManager: CBCentralManager!
  public var myPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
  public var writeCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic!
  public var DEVICENAME: String = ""
  public var result: String = ""

  public func initialBLE(cm: CBCentralManager){

    debugPrint("Process in initialBLE()")
    self.myCentralManager = cm
    myCentralManager.delegate = self
    debugPrint("Process in initialBLE(), myCentralManager=\(myCentralManager)"); 
    // here myCentralManager have a instance
}
```

then i use my own framework in viewcontroller, show as below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
  var  myCentralManager:CBCentralManager!
  var  myPeripheral:CBPeripheral!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myCentralManager = CBCentralManager()

    BLE().initialBLE(cm:myCentralManager)
    debugPrint("BLE().myCentralManager= \(BLE().self.myCentralManager)")
    // here is the problem, BLE().myCentralManager = nil
```

so how could I set a myCentralManager in framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see you are not holding a reference to the instance you have created. You should hold a reference and check `myCentralManager` on the same object.

```
let bleInstance = BLE().initialBLE(cm:myCentralManager)
// bleInstance.myCentralManager will have your desired value
```

Here you are creating a new instance of `BLE` and checking it's `myCentral` field without calling `initialBLE()` on it.

```
debugPrint("BLE().myCentralManager= \(BLE().self.myCentralManager)")
```

You are comparing two fresh instances. This is not about overriding `public` variables in frameworks.

Comment: i want to set myCentralManager(in ViewController) into BLE class (myCentralManager), but i have no idea ...

Comment: I see that you re a bit confused. Let's clarify things first.

You need to have a variable to hold your `BLE` instance. You can do as in my answer.

    `var bleInstance: BLE!`
    `var myCentralManager: CBCentralManager!`

   `bleInstance = BLE().initialBLE(cm:myCentralManager)`

After this point you can both reach to your `BLE` and `CBCentralManager` isntances in your VC

Comment: @ erenkabakci , thanks your help... i will try it later